Epsilon decays very quickly in DQN training
I'm trying to train a ViZDoom agent with Deep Reinforcement Learning. The problem I have is that the epsilon decays very quickly, and I'm not sure what to do. Any recommendations?
Previously, to decrease it I only had to multiply by the epsilon_decay, and it was decreasing with only a few steps. Now I'm decreasing it according to the number of steps, but it is still decreasing fast. I'm using Pytorch for the training.
Example image were the epsilon decay at 1000 steps until 2000 steps and the agent is trained fro 6000 steps
epsilon decay
I'm following this paper
ViZDoom: A Doom-based AI Research Platform
for Visual Reinforcement Learning
This is the training code:
def train(self):

    # code for train


    # calculate epsilon
    self.steps += 1

    if self.steps >= self.epsilon_decay_start:
        decay_steps = self.steps - self.epsilon_decay_start
        total_decay_steps = self.epsilon_decay_end - self.epsilon_decay_start
        self.epsilon = max(self.epsilon_min, self.epsilon - decay_steps * ((self.epsilon - self.epsilon_min) / total_decay_steps))

    return self.epsilon

This is the code where the agent is trained:
def train_agent(game, agent, actions, scenario, save_model, STEPS_TO_TRAIN, FRAME_REPEAT):
    max_steps = STEPS_TO_TRAIN
    steps_count = 0
    episode_count = 0
    episode_rewards = []
    epsilon_values = []
    max_reward = float('-inf')
    best_episode = -1

    print("Training")

    while steps_count < max_steps:
        recorded_episode = f"episode{episode_count}_rec.lmp"
        game.new_episode(recorded_episode)
    
        state = agent.preprocess(game.get_state().screen_buffer)
        total_reward = 0

        for step in it.count():
            if steps_count >= max_steps:
                break
            action = agent.select_action(state)
            reward = game.make_action(actions[action], FRAME_REPEAT)
            done = game.is_episode_finished()
            total_reward += reward
            next_state = agent.preprocess(game.get_state().screen_buffer) if not done else None
            agent.remember(state, action, next_state, reward)
            state = next_state
            steps_count += 1

            epsilon = agent.train()
            if epsilon is not None:
                epsilon_values.append(epsilon)
            if done:
                episode_rewards.append(total_reward)
                break

        if total_reward >= max_reward:
            max_reward = total_reward
            best_episode = episode_count

        if save_model:
            agent.save_model()

        episode_count += 1

And I am using these parameters:
# Q-learning settings
LEARNING_RATE = 0.01
GAMMA = 0.99 
BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
EPSILON = 1.0
EPSILON_DECAY_START = 100000
EPSILON_DECAY_END = 200000
EPSILON_MIN = 0.1
BATCH_SIZE = 40
# Other parameters
FRAME_REPEAT = 4
RESOLUTION = (60, 45)
STEPS_TO_TRAIN = 600000

